# code reusability in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I have three tables which are using using different variables for displaying the data.

Basic structure of the table

```
    <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th ng-repeat="var in array2"><i ng-show="array3[$index]=0"></th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="var in variable">
          <td ng-repeat="var1 in var">{{var1.position}}</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

All the three tables are using different arrays for variable, array2 and array3. Is there any way I don't have to write the code thrice and I can loop the code for three tables.

Please suggest changes in data structures only when there are no other possible HTML solution to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), for instance `<my-table-directive datas="array1"></my-table-directive>`

This directive will hold the logic and templaces and you'll pass a variable to define the content.